# My JTextPane doesn't get updated?

Tags: java, swing, polymorphism, jtextpane

My `TextPane` doesn't get updated, and I think it is because of my class structure.

My main question is how can I update my `TextPane` without changing this structure, because I like it?

Have in mind that I just post the relevant code.

First of all we start at creating my `JFrame`.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() throws HeadlessException {
        create Frame();
    }

    public void createFrame() {
        JSplitPane splitPane = content.determineJSplitpane();
        add(splitPane);
    }
}
```

The next one is my `determineSplitpane`. I need this method to define 3 areas.

```
public class KalenderFrameSplit {
    private FrameLeft left = new KalenderFrameLinks();
    private FrameMiddle middle = new KalenderFrameMitte();
    private FrameRight right = new KalenderFrameRechts();

    public JSplitPane determineJSplitpane() {
        JPanel leftPanel = this.left.leftArea();
        JScrollPane centerPanel = this.middle.middleArea();
        JPanel rightPanel = this.right.rightArea();

        JSplitPane splitPane1 = new JSplitPane();
        JSplitPane splitPane2 = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane1.setRightComponent(splitPane2);
        splitPane1.setLeftComponent(leftPanel);
        splitPane1.setEnabled(true);
        splitPane1.setDividerSize(3);

        splitPane2.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane2.setRightComponent(rightPanel);
        splitPane2.setLeftComponent(centerPanel);
        splitPane2.setDividerLocation(-2000);
        splitPane2.setEnabled(true);
        splitPane2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(4000, 0));
        splitPane2.setDividerSize(3);

        return splitPane1;
    }
}
```

The last one is my middle section class. I set the output with a radio button but I have made it easy with a method that sets the value of the `TextPane`. Later I must add style into the text. My teacher told me that I should use `Document` in a `TextPane` and that it gets updated automatically, but I have no idea how to do that.

```
public class FrameMiddle {

    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

    public JScrollPane middleArea() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        Document document;

        this.textPane.setText("");
        //this.textPane.setDocument();

        this.textPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(200, 200));
        this.textPane.setEditable(false);
        panel.add(textPane);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public void getContentOfTextPane() {
        this.textPane.setText("Hello World");
    }

}
```

I hope you guys can help me. I know that `public void getContentOfTextPane` isn't called but I want to ask the question as clean as possible. Because I ask this question but my question was not very clean and so I don't get any solution.

Comment: You'll want to simplify this code for us and post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Yeah. If you want I can post the hole project? or the hole code with setSize...

Comment: No, again you will want to create and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). **We definitely don't want to see your whole program**, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that any GUI change should be done from the Event Dispatched Thread.

Comment: What is the point of assigning a component layout as BorderLayout to a JTextPane ?